# How to declare record containing events which use record as parameter

Tags: delphi, types, declaration, cross-reference

I'm trying to figure out how to declare both a record and a number of object events which use each other. The problem is no matter which way I declare them, I have an "undeclared identifier".

So with the code below, can I get them to use each other? The events will be used in an object, and the record will be passed and used into the object's constructor.

```
  TMyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; var Rec: TMyRecord) of object;

  TMyRecord = record
    OnMyEvent: TMyEvent;
  end;
```

Is this possible? It needs to work in all versions of Delphi 7 and up.

Comment: +1. BTW: The var before Rec: PMyRecord isn't needed, unless your event handling code will be allocating a new record and assigning it to `Rec`. It's the same as when you pass an object; for instance, if you want to pass a `TStringList` into a procedure and add additional strings to it, you don't need to use `var SList: TStringList`, but can use `const SList: TStringList` instead.

Comment: @jerry you accepted the answer too quickly

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't think I did, because it did perfectly solve my problem, and the other answer I can't use. Just I didn't mention anything about being compatible with all versions down to 7.

Comment: well, you've changed the question now but before you did, allen's was the correct answer

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know dumb mistake for not mentioning compatibility. But I can't predict what I don't know, that's why I'm asking a question. If I knew that was possible I wouldn't have asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately forward declarations are only allowed for classes but not records, so the only way I know of is to use pointers:

```
PMyRecord = ^TMyRecord;

TMyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; Rec: PMyRecord) of object;

TMyRecord = record
  OnMyEvent: TMyEvent;
end;
```

Comment: The `var` before `Rec: PMyRecord` isn't needed, unless your event handling code will be changing the address of `Rec`. You can change the content of the record without it.

Comment: If I had to do that, I'd have just made it a class instead of a record.

Comment: This works perfect because I actually already use this record as a pointer in some places.

Answer (score 14):

If you're using a more recent Delphi version, you can declare types within records. Here is how you can reference the record from your event:

```
type
  TMyRecord = record
  public type
    TMyEvent = procedure (Sender: TObject; var Rec: TMyRecord) of object;
  public
    OnMyEvent: TMyEvent;
  end;
```

Comment: +1 This is the best solution here. One thing that I find limiting at the moment is the inability to have forward references for records when I am using operator overloading. I want rec A to have ops that operate on rec B, and vice versa. Tha's not possible at the moment in the language. But it could easily be. The operands are passed as pointers so the layout is not needed to be known at the point of declaration.

Comment: Addendum: I realise I can put all my ops in the latest declared record but I'd sometimes rather put them where they more naturally belong.

Comment: +1 That is really great to know, except a) I should have mentioned compatibility down to D7, and b) I need to use this event type elsewhere

Comment: @jerry use it elsewhere as TMyRecord.TMyEvent